# wx.NotificationMessage AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NotificationMessage'

Tags: python, linux, wxpython

I get this error when trying to use wxPython's NotificationMessage class:

wx.NotificationMessage("", "Hello world!").Show()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NotificationMessage'

The code is quite simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import wx

app = wx.App()

wx.NotificationMessage("", "Hello world!").Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

What am I missing?

This is running on Linux Mint 13, MATE 1.2 desktop environment, Python 2.7.3.

Comment: What version of wxPython? From what I can tell, wx.NotificationMessage [is only in version 2.9](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Request-for-an-example-of-using-wx-NotificationMessage-td2374706.html). The current "stable" release is 2.8, but most people have switched to 2.9. See ["Development Release"](http://wxpython.org/download.php)

Comment: Ah, I knew it'd be something daft like that. Yeah, wxPython 2.8 here. Will update, thanks a lot

Comment: If it makes you feel better, a similar issue involving [wx.WrapSizer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411830/does-wxpython-have-a-native-flowlayoutmanager-flowsizer-wrapsizer-implementation) is what pushed me to register to SO. Anyone new to wxpython will look at the website and download the latest stable version without continuing to read and discover that most people should be using 2.9.

Answer (score 0):

NotificationMessage is part of the wx 2.9 library which is not installed as standard by any of the package managers. If you are wanting to use this you will need to download and install manually from http://www.wxpython.org/